# How do you transfer AWS RDS snap shot to a different AWS account

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS database that I need to transfer a snapshot of to another AWS account. I understand there are issues being able to do this between availability zones so I'm really unsure if this is possible.

The RDS instance is mySql.

If it's not possible to transfer the snapshot please could you explain how to transfer the data from one RDS instance to another without downloading any if the contents(The DB is over 200GB).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've decided that currently the only way to solve the problem is by creating a server in the second account and doing a database dump from mySQL to a mounted volume.

This can then be restored to the new RDS instance in the second account.

Comment: It seems that AWS make it very easy to get in but very hard to get out.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon finally made it possible to accomplish this. I like to use AWS Tools for PowerShell to code it, but you can find equivalent commands in awscli or other SDKs.

You can share the snapshot with another account using the Edit-RDSDBSnapshotAttribute cmdlet ([example here](http://www.dataasapet.com/2016/03/12/how-to-share-an-rds-snapshot-with-aws-tools-for-windows-powershell/)), then you can restore it to an account the snapshot was shared with using the Restore-RDSDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot cmdlet.

You can even share encrypted snapshots now. Here's [a good walkthrough](http://www.dataasapet.com/2016/03/09/how-to-share-an-encrypted-rds-snapshot-with-another-aws-account/) on how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

We transfer AMI snapshots via S3, I guess the same works for RDS snapshots.

You can use the S3Fox Firefox addon for this.

Comment: Unfortunatley this will not work as RDS snapshots cant be accessed in the same way AMI snapshots are. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Can you export it as a VM image to a local copy, and upload it to the other account as a image as well?  check out http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/   It is still in beta, so may or may not be able do work it with RDS, ask amazon i'd say